# Retopoflow needs an update?

Tags: add-on

So I would like to use Retopoflow for Blender 2.8 but it requires an update by the looks of it, so I searched around for a solution but no luck. Any idea on how to update it? Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retopoflow is an add-on that is still in heavy development, and the authors would need to do the work to update it since there are many changes in the way Blender handles graphics now, as well as API changes for python.

Comment: So in other words it's still in development for 2.8?

Comment: It is still in development, yes. Adapting to 2.8 isn't going to be quick as they are still working on things from 2.79b users as well. My money says that they have it available once we have a stable 2.80a release (we are only in Beta right now).

Comment: do you think finishing the 2.8 models and importing them to 2.79b then doing the retopology would be a viable alternative? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do that, treat 2.79b as your Retopoflow application and then bring the retopo result in 2.8, that is already how I handle it here.

Comment: umm thanks for the help for when I transfer the mesh the tools are doing nothing?

Comment: The result mesh brought into 2.8 doesn't allow you to edit it? Make sure you have selected the new object. If you are having problems with the import, try saving it as a blend and opening in 2.8.

Comment: no I import my mesh I made in 2.8 to 2.79b but it won't let me edit it with retopoflow it's like the tools do nothing

Comment: Did you import obj or append the object from the blend file? I get no problem here with append of the object from the 2.80 blend file.

Comment: well I don't know what it falls under but I hit control c on the blender 2.8 object and open 2.79b then hit control v and it just showed up.

Comment: I can't do that here. I append from the file. Try that.

Comment: umm I spawned in a cylinder and Retopoflow wouldn't work for that either. It is also spawning in vertices that do nothing...help please :(

Comment: You may need to file a bug report with the retopoflow devs on the github.

Comment: But how come no one else has been affected man this has been haunting me for ages I just can't finish anything cause I cant retopologize :(

Comment: I see bug fixes come across the mailing list all the time. It works fine in mesh generated in 2.79b for me as well as mesh imported. If you have the latest update for both programs and the add on then file a bug report. This thread was about when the add on was to be updated to 2.8, and that topic is resolved. They answer emails pretty quickly, so be ready to give them an example file.

Comment: Oh what version of Retopoflow are you using for 2.79b I just rolled back to 2.0 and it now shows some edge lines but nothing still happens.

Answer (score 3):

I would have preferred to post this as a comment but I need to have 50 reputation to do that.

As has been stated, the authors have stated that a 2.80 version will be produced and that work would begin once the API had stabilised. I would assume from that the at least initial work has therefore begun as the API was declared as stable when the public beta launched.

The point I wanted to contribute however was a tip on working between versions. I have found a number of issues with the import/export addons, which again translate back to the current beta status and the fact that most import/export is considered as an addon to the core functionality and thus lower priority.

What has worked really well for me so far is (surprisingly) copy/paste. It will no doubt depend a lot on the structure of your objects but in my case I have been able to select the objects I need to retopo while in 2.8, ctrl-C to copy them, then tab over to Blender 2.79b and paste them in (ctrl-V). Occasionally I find the copy/paste buffer is not picked up, but reselecting and repeating fixes that so I suspect human frailty more than bugs, is responsible for that.

I hope this helps. Perhaps a Mod might copy this up to a comment on Craig's response as it's not really adding anything new to his answer but simply offering some further hints for Craig's suggested workflow.